# Modifying headers of a Mail::Message returned by ActionMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

I'm currently running into an issue with sending e-mails from ActionMailer. I'm trying to append a custom header onto every e-mail sent from my system, regardless of what mailer it is coming from. The header contains information about which person is receiving the e-mail, so it can't be setup in the defaults of the mailer, but I'd like to avoid needing to set up this header in each individual mailer.

Here's what I have set up currently:

```
  candidates.each do |c|
    mail = mailer_class.send(action.to_sym, c, params)
    recip = email_recipients.create!(:contact => c, :subject => mail.subject)

    mail.headers['X-SMTPAPI'] = {:unique_args => {:email_recipient_id => recip.id, :database => Apartment::Database.current_database }, 
                                 :category => "#{mailer}-#{action}" }.to_json

    mail.deliver
  end
```

The problem is, setting a key on the `headers` hash of a `Mail::Message` doesn't seem to change anything.

I did find a way to set a header by manually setting the header property, like so:

```
m.header = m.header.to_s + "\nBlah: Blah"
```

But to be honest, this feels a little hacky. Does anyone know of a better pattern to accomplish this?

Comment: Are you sending json over smtp headers?

Comment: Yeah. A bit weird, but that's dictated by a provider I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a class that extends the ActionMailer::Base with the default headers

in the **initializers** directory add a file that gets loaded that looks like

**mailer_defaults.rb**

```
  class ActionMailer::Base
    def defaults
      # header HERE 
    end
 end
```

This should take you on the right directions